# What happens if I move defined as word value size of byte to 32 bit register as if it was dword defined?

Tags: assembly, x86

Here's the code:

```
;NASM

section .data
a dw 0xDEAD

section .text 
...
mov eax, dword [a + 1]
; eax now equals 0xDE
...
```

So, how does this work? Assembly knows that if I move more bytes than there's defined, then it just adds zeroes at the higher bits? Or may be this code just worked for me and generally it's undefined behavior or sth like that?

Comment: `a` is a `dword`. `a + 1` is the next `dword` after `a`. What value does it have? Is is properly initialized? What results from using uninitialized values? (your UB comment is right on target) Add `b dw 0xBEEF` and re-run your code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `a` is the only variable I use. So, I added `b dw 0xBEEF` and now eax equals `0xBEEFDE`. Alright, that means that `mov` takes next 24 bits after `a` and in my case they all are zeroes? Results from using uninitialized values are the same as for defined.

Comment: Yes, but the risk is there is no guarantee what is in bytes that have not been initialized. So always make sure the memory you are reading from contains valid data. Good luck with your assembly. `nasm` is a good assembler.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your computer turns into a smoking desert of rubble, that's "defined" for assembly. The "type cast" `dword` in `mov eax, dword [a + 1]` just informs the assembler that you know what you're doing and don't want to get a warning or error. In the object file, the types have disappeared, and the processor don't know that you move more bytes than there's defined.

The processor reads 4 bytes from the address a+1 and there are randomly or not randomly the values `DE 00 00 00`. How those zeros got there doesn't matter. It may be that NASM has the text segment aligned, it may be that the operating system has requested a whole page (4096 bytes) for the data segment and has filled the rest with zeros, it may be that the text segment starts with zeros, because the entry point is further back. It is also possible that the behavior of the program will change randomly at some point.

TLDR: Dont do it!

Comment: `section .data` is linked in a separate segment from `section .text`; alignment of the text section/segment is irrelevant.  (Unless you use a linker script to get them mapped to adjacent pages; that's not the case normally, so out-of-bounds array accesses are less likely to load code instead of faulting.)  Data and BSS can be in the same segment (and thus in the same page), if `.data` is small, but not text and data.  But anyway yes, depending what you link with, `a` could be at the end of a page, with `a+2` in an unmapped page, so the load could fault.  Or just overlap later data.

Answer (score 2):

```
a dw 0xDEAD
```

Tells assembler to store 2 bytes (DW - Define Word(16bit), btw - DB = 8bit, DD=32bit) and use `a` to point to it. Since (I bet so) you are using x86-64 machine, it is 'little endian' which means it stores multibyte values starting from least significant byte first so in memory your `0xDEAD` value will be stored like so: `0xAD` first, `0xDE` next. Since your data segment is for sure padded to be multiple of say 16 bytes (for example) it is probably padded with zeros. Now if we assume your data segment is 16 bytes - first 2 define your `a` variable - the rest will be zeroes.

Now the data segment looks like this (assuming zero padding to 16 bytes) (hex values without 0x prefix):

```
AD, DE, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0
    ^
     \__ (a+1) points here at DE
```

By writing `dword ptr [a + 1]` you tell your assembler to encode such machine code instruction in a way which will grab `dword` (4 bytes) from address `a+1`.
These will be bytes:
    DE, 0, 0, 0
Since (as I said earlier) x86 is little endian these 4 bytes if read as 4 byte value mean `0x00000DE` hence EAX equals to this value.

Of course your data segment might not be 16 bytes but is probably full page length but it is meaningless.

Comment: And if you had anything else in `.data` after `a dw 0xdead`, a 4-byte load would grab bytes from that.  (Also, the space after it is not necessarily padded with zeros, although zero padding up to at least some alignment boundary is common)